# How to set up IPSec Xauth RSA client on Mikrotik/RouterOS?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, mikrotik

I would need to configure *IPSec Xauth RSA* client on Microrik. I have such client working on Android. I have all necessary certificates provided along with Username/Password.

Is it [ever](https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=85489) [possible](https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=124013)?

If so - what would be the related auth-method for Mikrotik setup?

RouterBOARD 750G r3, fw 6.41.1

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, yes. The only limit is that you can only authenticate using CHAP; none of the EAP authentication methods are currently available. It works by changing the auth-method to *rsa-signature-hybrid* (certificates + xauth). Here's an example configuration:

```
/ip ipsec peer
add address=172.16.0.2 auth-method=rsa-signature-hybrid certificate=cert.p12
    mode-config=request-only exchange-mode=ike2 generate-policy=port-strict
    xauth-login=username xauth-password=password
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the [MikroTik manual](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/IPsec) regarding IPsec. There's a lot of info and examples there.

Here's an XAuth example from the manual.

> Simple Mutual PSK XAuth Config
>
> Server side config:
>
> ```
> /ip ipsec peer
> add address=2.2.2.1 auth-method=pre-shared-key-xauth secret="123" passive=yes
> /ip ipsec user
> add name=test password=345
> ```
>
> Client side config:
>
> ```
> /ip ipsec peer
> add address=2.2.2.2 auth-method=pre-shared-key-xauth secret="123" \
>   xauth-login=test xauth-password=345
> ```
>
> *Note: On server side it is mandatory to set passive to yes when XAuth*
>   *is used.*

Comment: Thank you for advice. I have had alrady read manual and 3 books on subj. My question still stands. I hope you understand the diff between psk and pki.